# Change dictionary into label array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, cluster-analysis

So I have a 2d array

```
X = [[ 7.3571296   0.49626   ]
 [-0.7747436   3.14599   ]
 [ 3.7817762   4.1808457 ]
 [ 4.5332413   6.8228664 ]
 [ 7.4655724  -0.11392868]
 [ 2.416418    4.692072  ]]
```

and a cluster label array.

```
y = [1 3 2 2 1 3]
```

Then I have an algorithm that can predict the label of the 2d array.

```
Z = {1: array([[ 7.3571296   0.49626   ],
               [ 7.4655724  -0.11392868]]), 
     2: array([[ 3.7817762   4.1808457 ]
               [ 2.416418    4.692072  ]]),
     3: array([[-0.7747436   3.14599   ],
               [ 4.5332413   6.8228664 ]])}
```

I want to match my predicted label with original label to know my algorithm's accuracy. But how can I extract the dictionary format into label array format? (i.e. y_pred = [1 3 2 3 1 2])

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keys()` method of the dictionary and cast it to `list`.

```
import numpy as np

Z = {1: np.asarray([[7.3571296, 0.49626], [7.4655724, 0.11392868]]),
     2: np.asarray([[3.7817762, 4.1808457], [2.416418, 4.692072]]),
     3: np.asarray([[-0.7747436, 3.14599], [4.5332413, 6.8228664]])}

print(list(Z.keys())) #[1, 2, 3]
```